# lzw string - Sending via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, server, lzw

I am using LZW algorithm for stringified JSON object to reduce size. Size reduction is fantastic, but I am having problems transmitting compressed string via AJAX because of URL malformed error. If I encode it with base64, the size goes up enormously.

What are the practices to send LZW compressed data to server ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: `I am having problems transmitting compressed string via AJAX because of URL malformed error.`do you send it in the Post-body? plz. show the code for your ajax-request.

Comment: @Thomas: I am using standard jQuery Ajax POST call and I am putting my compressed string into data array of the call.